# Plotting undirected graph in python using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using networkx to plot graph in python. However, my output is too dense. Is there any ways to sparse the graph? Below is my command in python.Thanks

```
    pos=nx.spring_layout(self.G)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(self.G,pos)
    edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
             for u,v,d in self.G.edges(data=True)])
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(self.G,pos, font_size=20,font_family='sans-serif')
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(self.G,pos)
    plt.axis('off')
    #nx.draw_networkx_labels(self.G,pos, font_size=20,font_family='sans-serif')
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(self.G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
    nx.draw(self.G,pos, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds)

    plt.show()
```

[image: sample graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) via [PyDot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) (I prefer this one) or [PyGraphviz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphviz).

In case you are interested in a publication-ready result, you can use the toolchain `networkx` -> `pydot` + `dot` -> [`dot2tex`](https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex) + `dot` -> [`dot2texi.sty`](https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2texisty) -> [`TikZ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ). Instead of this fragile toolchain, you can alternatively export directly to `TikZ` with [`nx2tikz`](https://github.com/johnyf/nx2tikz) (I've written it, so I'm biased) and use the graph layout algorithms that have been relatively recently added to `TikZ`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience

Answer (score 0):

After I check some information from the documentation here: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout

I changed the format of layout to

```
pos=nx.circular_layout(self.G, scale=5)
```

and it works!
[image]